# relative URL not working with axios in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url, relative-path

On my node server, the following code works

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/myPath') // works
```

But relative pathes don't work

```
axios.get('/myPath') // doesn't work
```

I get this error :

> message:"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80" port:80

How can I get the relative url work like in the browser ?

Relative path should be hitting on port 8080, not 80.

Where do I set that on my node server ?

Answer (score 7):

Create a new instance with custom configuation. like below

> var instance = axios.create({
>      baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080'
>   });
>
> instance.get('/myPath', {
>     timeout: 5000
>   });

Hope, this will works
Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: Rather than hard-coding the basURL, you could get the origin from the request header (i.e. req.headers.origin)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a relative URL in this scenario because there's nothing for it to be relative to - you're executing code in a script running on the server, not in a browser. It doesn't have any concept of a "current" URL to be relative to.

You'll need to explicitly specify the full domain name and port. If this causes you a problem (e.g. because you want to deploy this to different hosts without changing the code) you'll have to inject the values into your code another way (e.g. by reading from a config file, cf. [documentation here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration)).

Comment: "something on a different port" — It isn't on a different port. There isn't anything to be relative to. The code isn't running in a browser.

Comment: @Quentin ah ok so we're talking about the code executing server-side in a node environment. Sorry, I missed that part somehow. Will amend the answer.