# Axios error (404) in React.js / Firebase app: POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios, http-status-code-404

I have a problem: I can't connect frontend (react.js) with backend (firebase).
For that, I use `Axios.js`.
When I try to log in, I've got an error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login 404 (Not Found)
```

A snippet from **login.js**

```
    handleSubmit =(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })
        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        axios
            .post('/login', userData)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
                this.setState({
                    loading: false
                })
                this.props.history.push('/')
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.setState({
                    errors: err.response.data,
                    loading: false
                })
            })
}
```

The same problem is with getting data from backend.

```
GET  http://localhost:3000/gossips 404 (Not Found)  
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"

import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

import Gossip from '../components/Gossip'

class home extends Component {
    state = {
        gossips: null
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('/gossips')
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    gossips: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })

    }

    render() {
        let recentGossipsMarkup = this.state.gossips ? (
            this.state.gossips.map((gossip) => <Gossip key={gossip.gossipId} gossip={gossip} />)
        ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
        )
        return (
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentGossipsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

export default home
```

`Axios` is imported in these `js files` and the proxy is set in `package.json`.
I can't figure out where I made mistake.

```
**package.json**    
    {
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "proxy": [
      "https://europe-west1-chit-chat-75481.cloudfunctions.net/api"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "firebase": "^8.2.5",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "name": "chit-chat",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  }
}
```

By the way, all routes work in `Postman`

Can anyone please help me to fix these errors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post you code as images but rather as the `code sample` given in the question editor.

Comment: can you try to add the entire url in the `axios.get()` function instead of just `/gossips` exactly the same as your postman test 
see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52947579/14522591)

Comment: @antoineso thanx, I tried that already but it didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy needs to be a string like this.

```
"proxy": "https://europe-west1-chit-chat-75481.cloudfunctions.net/api"
```

And it also need to be in the root of the file not nested under `browserslist` as you have it.

Note that you need to restart your react app after making changes to your `package.json` file.